# return null UITextView tag in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfielddelegate

I put 10 UITextField inside UITableViewCell and put tags on every UITextField.

My question is, can I access the tags of those UITextFields in

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField?
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, can I access the tags of those UITextFields in
>   `-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`?

Sure. Just use:

```
textField.tag
```

The method `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` is called for a specific field, and that field will be specified in the `textField` parameter. If you want to access a *different* field, then you'll need to get a pointer to the field you want. You could do something like:

```
UIView *parent = [textField superview];
UITextField *someOtherField = [parent viewWithTag:theTagOfTheFieldYouWant];
```

Comment: the code is like this:&nbsp;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {       
        ...
        int rowCount = indexPath.row;    
        NavigationObject *navigationObj = [self.navigations objectAtIndex:rowCount];
        cell.cellWayPoint.text = navigationObj.waypoint;
        cell.cellWayPoint.tag = indexPath.row;
        cell.cellWayPoint.delegate = self;
    return cell;    
}

Comment: - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"Currently editing textfield. with data: %@",textField.tag);
    [self animateTextField: textField up: YES];
}